Lifetime issues with async closure in rust
I want to wrap an db transaction from the diesel-async crate into a generic connection object that provides an async transaction method on its own. Unfortunately, whatever I try the borrow checker complains about my lifetimes and I don't understand them good enough yet to solve this on my own.
Quick overview:

Service handles the business logic and is agnostic about the way the data is persisted. I added this part to my example because in some of my tries the borrow checker complained about the Send requirement in the service function and some resulting lifetime constraints
Repository takes care of data persistence. For this it needs to have a connection to a database
Connection provides such a db connection including a transaction method

Most parts of the code should work, except of the transaction method.
My questions are:

How can I fix the lifetimes? I might run into similar cases again and would like to learn this.
In case of diesel, is there a better way than wrapping the diesel-provided closure into another closure? The part with storing a mutable reference in my connection wrapper looks kind of messy.

# Cargo.toml

[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.0.0", features = ["rt", "rt-multi-thread", "macros"] }
diesel = { version = "2.2.4", features = ["postgres"]}
diesel-async = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["postgres"] }

// main.rs

use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

use diesel_async::{AsyncConnection, AsyncPgConnection};
use diesel_async::scoped_futures::ScopedFutureExt;

// Business logic as async functions that can be shared between threads
trait Service: Send + Sync + 'static {

    /// Update value of item if new value is larger than current value.
    /// Example functino that needs multiple repo functions
    fn maximize_item(&self, id: i32, value: i32) -> impl Future<Output=Result<i32, String>> + Send;
}

// Persist the data in e.g. a database
// The repository provides a new connection and expects that repo methods are called with
trait Repository: Send + Sync + 'static {
    type Conn: Connection;

    /// Connect to data storage, or throw error if attempt failed
    fn connect(&self) -> impl Future<Output=Result<Self::Conn, String>> + Send;

    /// Get current value for item, or throw error if item doesn't exist or value is not retrievable
    fn get_item_value(&self, conn: &mut Self::Conn, id: i32) -> impl Future<Output=Result<i32, String>> + Send;

    /// Update value for item, or throw error if item doesn't exist or can't be updated
    fn update_item_value(&self, conn: &mut Self::Conn, id: i32, value: i32) -> impl Future<Output=Result<i32, String>> + Send;
}


// Connection to some data storage
trait Connection: AsMut<Self::SpecificConn> + Send + Sync + 'static {
    type SpecificConn: Send + Sync;

    /// Provide a generic transaction as closure that is agnostic to the underlying db or ORM.
    /// Commit if closure returns Ok`, rollback on `Err`
    // THe lifetimes are wrong, and possibly more, but I don't know how to fix this method
    fn transaction<'a, F, R>(&'a mut self, callback: F) -> impl Future<Output=Result<R, String>> + Send
    where
        F: FnOnce(&'a mut Self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<R, String>> + Send>> + Send,
        R: Send;
}

struct ServiceImpl<R: Repository> {
    repo: R, // service holds a generic repository to persist date
}

// implementation for Service while keeping the repository generic
impl<R: Repository> Service for ServiceImpl<R> {

    // The service methods sometimes need to call multiple repository functions, but need
    // to ensure this is done as an atomic transaction. Instead of writing business logic to roll
    // back failed attempts on my own, I rather want to use a database transaction for this
    async fn maximize_item(&self, id: i32, value: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {

        // get new db connection wrapped into a generic object
        let mut conn = self.repo.connect().await?;

        // wrap repository tasks into an atomic but generic transaction. The repo needs
        // to ensure a transaction is atomic
        conn.transaction(|conn: &mut R::Conn| Box::pin(async move {

            // get value and update value are different methods, but
            // should be executed as atomic transaction here
            let current = self.repo.get_item_value(conn, id).await?;
            if value > current {
                let updated = self.repo.update_item_value(conn, id, value).await?;
                Ok(updated)
            } else {
                Ok(current)
            }
        })).await
    }
}

struct RepositoryForSpecificDbType;

// implement the repository for a specific database and ORM (or a mock for testing).
// In this case it is Postgres with Diesel
impl<'a> Repository for RepositoryForSpecificDbType {
    type Conn = ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'a>;

    // wrap diesel connection to postgres db into a generic connection object
    async fn connect(&self) -> Result<ConnectionToSpecificDbType, String> {
        let dsn = "postgres:://root:****@localhost:my_db";
        let conn = AsyncPgConnection::establish(dsn).await.map_err(|_| "Connection failed".to_string())?;
        Ok(ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new(conn))
    }

    async fn get_item_value(&self, _conn: &mut Self::Conn, id: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
        // mocking some database lookup
        Ok(id * 2)
    }

    async fn update_item_value(&self, _conn: &mut Self::Conn, _id: i32, value: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
        // mocking some database update
        Ok(value)
    }
}

struct ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'c> {
    /// conn holds the connection as long as it is new
    conn: Option<AsyncPgConnection>,

    // conn mut holds the connection as mutable reference when constructed inside
    // the diesel transaction closure
    conn_mut: Option<&'c mut AsyncPgConnection>,
}

impl<'c> ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'_> {
    fn new(conn: AsyncPgConnection) -> ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'c> {
        ConnectionToSpecificDbType {
            conn: Some(conn),
            conn_mut: None,
        }
    }

    fn new_from_mut(conn: &'c mut AsyncPgConnection) -> ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'c> {
        ConnectionToSpecificDbType {
            conn: None,
            conn_mut: Some(conn),
        }
    }
}

// get mutable reference to connection
impl<'c> AsMut<AsyncPgConnection> for ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'_> {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut AsyncPgConnection {
        // the struct can own the postgres connection outside the closure or hold a mutable reference if inside the closure
        // is there a better way to handle this?
        if self.conn.is_some() { self.conn.as_mut().unwrap() } else { self.conn_mut.as_mut().unwrap() }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum TransactionError<E: Send + Sync> {
    UserCaused(E),
    DieselCaused(diesel::result::Error),
}

// A diesel transaction requires that a closure error implements `From<Error>`.
// To stay generic, handle errors in the closure and translate them into a generic error
impl<E: Send + Sync> From<diesel::result::Error> for TransactionError<E> {
    fn from(value: diesel::result::Error) -> Self {
        TransactionError::DieselCaused(value)
    }
}

impl<'c> Connection for ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'_> {
    type SpecificConn = AsyncPgConnection;

    // This function doesn't work
    // it should provide a generic abstraction of a transaction
    async fn transaction<'a, F, R>(&'a mut self, callback: F) -> Result<R, String>
    where
        F: FnOnce(&'a mut Self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<R, String>> + Send>> + Send,
        R: Send,
    {
        let result = self.as_mut().transaction(|diesel_conn| async move {

            // wrap mut ref to diesel connection into connection object that implements Connection
            let mut inner_conn = ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new_from_mut(diesel_conn);

            // call closure
            let result = callback(&mut inner_conn).await;

            // translate into generic intermediate error type that implements From<Error>
            result.map_err(|e| TransactionError::UserCaused(e))
        }.scope_boxed()).await;

        // return result
        result.map_err(|e| format!("{e:?}").to_string())
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // create a new service instance and define which repository implementation is used
    let service = ServiceImpl {
        repo: RepositoryForSpecificDbType
    };

    assert_eq!(service.maximize_item(5, 3).await.unwrap(), 10);
    assert_eq!(service.maximize_item(5, 8).await.unwrap(), 10);
    assert_eq!(service.maximize_item(5, 13).await.unwrap(), 13);
    assert_eq!(service.maximize_item(5, 21).await.unwrap(), 21);
}

This is the current list of compiler errors I get:
error[E0597]: `conn` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:61:9
   |
57 |           let mut conn = self.repo.connect().await?;
   |               -------- binding `conn` declared here
...
61 |           conn.transaction(|conn: &mut R::Conn| Box::pin(async move {
   |  _________^^^^__________________________________-
   | |         |
   | |         borrowed value does not live long enough
62 | |
63 | |             // get value and update value are different methods, but
64 | |             // should be executed as atomic transaction here
...  |
71 | |             }
72 | |         })).await
   | |__________- returning this value requires that `conn` is borrowed for `'static`
73 |       }
   |       - `conn` dropped here while still borrowed

error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:61:47
   |
54 |       async fn maximize_item(&self, id: i32, value: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
   |                              - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
61 |           conn.transaction(|conn: &mut R::Conn| Box::pin(async move {
   |  _______________________________________________^
62 | |
63 | |             // get value and update value are different methods, but
64 | |             // should be executed as atomic transaction here
...  |
71 | |             }
72 | |         })).await
   | |__________^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

error[E0597]: `inner_conn` does not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:165:35
    |
154 |     async fn transaction<'a, F, R>(&'a mut self, callback: F) -> Result<R, String>
    |                          -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
162 |             let mut inner_conn = ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new_from_mut(diesel_conn);
    |                 -------------- binding `inner_conn` declared here
...
165 |             let result = callback(&mut inner_conn).await;
    |                          ---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
    |                          |        |
    |                          |        borrowed value does not live long enough
    |                          argument requires that `inner_conn` is borrowed for `'a`
...
169 |         }.scope_boxed()).await;
    |         - `inner_conn` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of closure
   --> src/main.rs:162:34
    |
149 | impl<'c> Connection for ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'_> {
    |                                                    -- lifetime `'2` appears in the `impl`'s self type
...
159 |         let result = self.as_mut().transaction(|diesel_conn| async move {
    |                                                 -----------
    |                                                 |
    |                                                 `diesel_conn` is a reference that is only valid in the closure body
    |                                                 has type `&'1 mut AsyncPgConnection`
...
162 |             let mut inner_conn = ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new_from_mut(diesel_conn);
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                                  |
    |                                  `diesel_conn` escapes the closure body here
    |                                  assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`

error[E0311]: the parameter type `F` may not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:159:22
    |
149 |   impl<'c> Connection for ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'_> {
    |                                                      -- the parameter type `F` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime as defined here...
...
159 |           let result = self.as_mut().transaction(|diesel_conn| async move {
    |  ______________________^
160 | |
161 | |             // wrap mut ref to diesel connection into connection object that implements Connection
162 | |             let mut inner_conn = ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new_from_mut(diesel_conn);
...   |
168 | |             result.map_err(|e| TransactionError::UserCaused(e))
169 | |         }.scope_boxed()).await;
    | |________________________^ ...so that the type `F` will meet its required lifetime bounds
    |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
    |
149 ~ impl<'a, 'c> Connection for ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'a> {
150 |     type SpecificConn = AsyncPgConnection;
...
155 |     where
156 ~         F: FnOnce(&'a mut Self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<R, String>> + Send>> + Send + 'a,
    |

error[E0309]: the parameter type `F` may not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:159:22
    |
154 |       async fn transaction<'a, F, R>(&'a mut self, callback: F) -> Result<R, String>
    |                            -- the parameter type `F` must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
...
159 |           let result = self.as_mut().transaction(|diesel_conn| async move {
    |  ______________________^
160 | |
161 | |             // wrap mut ref to diesel connection into connection object that implements Connection
162 | |             let mut inner_conn = ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new_from_mut(diesel_conn);
...   |
168 | |             result.map_err(|e| TransactionError::UserCaused(e))
169 | |         }.scope_boxed()).await;
    | |________________________^ ...so that the type `F` will meet its required lifetime bounds
    |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
    |
156 |         F: FnOnce(&'a mut Self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<R, String>> + Send>> + Send + 'a,
    |                                                                                                 ++++

error[E0311]: the parameter type `R` may not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:159:22
    |
149 |   impl<'c> Connection for ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'_> {
    |                                                      -- the parameter type `R` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime as defined here...
...
159 |           let result = self.as_mut().transaction(|diesel_conn| async move {
    |  ______________________^
160 | |
161 | |             // wrap mut ref to diesel connection into connection object that implements Connection
162 | |             let mut inner_conn = ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new_from_mut(diesel_conn);
...   |
168 | |             result.map_err(|e| TransactionError::UserCaused(e))
169 | |         }.scope_boxed()).await;
    | |________________________^ ...so that the type `R` will meet its required lifetime bounds
    |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
    |
149 ~ impl<'a, 'c> Connection for ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'a> {
150 |     type SpecificConn = AsyncPgConnection;
...
156 |         F: FnOnce(&'a mut Self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<R, String>> + Send>> + Send,
157 ~         R: Send + 'a,
    |

error[E0309]: the parameter type `R` may not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:159:22
    |
154 |       async fn transaction<'a, F, R>(&'a mut self, callback: F) -> Result<R, String>
    |                            -- the parameter type `R` must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
...
159 |           let result = self.as_mut().transaction(|diesel_conn| async move {
    |  ______________________^
160 | |
161 | |             // wrap mut ref to diesel connection into connection object that implements Connection
162 | |             let mut inner_conn = ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new_from_mut(diesel_conn);
...   |
168 | |             result.map_err(|e| TransactionError::UserCaused(e))
169 | |         }.scope_boxed()).await;
    | |________________________^ ...so that the type `R` will meet its required lifetime bounds
    |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
    |
157 |         R: Send + 'a,
    |                 ++++

error[E0311]: the parameter type `F` may not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:159:62
    |
149 |   impl<'c> Connection for ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'_> {
    |                                                      -- the parameter type `F` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime as defined here...
...
159 |           let result = self.as_mut().transaction(|diesel_conn| async move {
    |  ______________________________________________________________^
160 | |
161 | |             // wrap mut ref to diesel connection into connection object that implements Connection
162 | |             let mut inner_conn = ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new_from_mut(diesel_conn);
...   |
168 | |             result.map_err(|e| TransactionError::UserCaused(e))
169 | |         }.scope_boxed()).await;
    | |_______________________^ ...so that the type `F` will meet its required lifetime bounds
    |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
    |
149 ~ impl<'a, 'c> Connection for ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'a> {
150 |     type SpecificConn = AsyncPgConnection;
...
155 |     where
156 ~         F: FnOnce(&'a mut Self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<R, String>> + Send>> + Send + 'a,
    |

error[E0309]: the parameter type `F` may not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:159:62
    |
154 |       async fn transaction<'a, F, R>(&'a mut self, callback: F) -> Result<R, String>
    |                            -- the parameter type `F` must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
...
159 |           let result = self.as_mut().transaction(|diesel_conn| async move {
    |  ______________________________________________________________^
160 | |
161 | |             // wrap mut ref to diesel connection into connection object that implements Connection
162 | |             let mut inner_conn = ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new_from_mut(diesel_conn);
...   |
168 | |             result.map_err(|e| TransactionError::UserCaused(e))
169 | |         }.scope_boxed()).await;
    | |_______________________^ ...so that the type `F` will meet its required lifetime bounds
    |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
    |
156 |         F: FnOnce(&'a mut Self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<R, String>> + Send>> + Send + 'a,
    |                                                                                                 ++++

error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:80:6
   |
80 | impl<'a> Repository for RepositoryForSpecificDbType {
   |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter

error[E0478]: lifetime bound not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:149:10
    |
149 | impl<'c> Connection for ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'_> {
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: lifetime parameter instantiated with the anonymous lifetime as defined here
   --> src/main.rs:149:52
    |
149 | impl<'c> Connection for ConnectionToSpecificDbType<'_> {
    |                                                    ^^
    = note: but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime

error: aborting due to 12 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0207, E0309, E0311, E0478, E0521, E0597.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0207`.
error: could not compile `async_closure` (bin "async_closure") due to 13 previous errors
Process finished with exit code 101


After the code has been cleaned up a little, one of rust's most annoying bugs is hit (the compiler even outputs "this is a known limitation that will be removed in the future"). I managed to get the code to compile, but I am not knowledgeable enough to write a proper answer (for example, adding a Send bound brings back errors which aren't even related to Send): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8ea4ad2347bf0592be1d9240aae0a96c

The code finally compiles!
The partial solution in the comment by @trueequalsfalse uses transmute() to turn the mutable reference to the diesel connection into a ConnectionToSpecificDbType without the necessity of adding a lifetime to ConnectionToSpecificDbType.
The transaction() function in diesel-async uses boxed futures and the async-trait crate to encapsulate the lifetimes of the transaction there.
I combined both approaches to wrap the diesel transaction into a generic transaction.
I also added a mock for the diesel connection at the end, so that the code can be executed without db.
For completeness, the reason I wanted to use generic connection is that I wanted to try out this guide on Hexagonal Architecture, but needed transactions in my Service impl, which were not covered in the guide.
# Cargo.toml

[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.0.0", features = ["rt", "rt-multi-thread", "macros"] }
diesel = { version = "2.2.4", features = ["postgres"] }
diesel-async = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["postgres"] }
async-trait = "0.1.83"
scoped-futures = "0.1.3"

All changes to the original code in the question are marked with ***.
#[deny(unsafe_code)] // *** added
use std::future::Future;

use scoped_futures::{ScopedBoxFuture, ScopedFutureExt}; // ** changed

use crate::diesel_async_mock::{AsyncConnection, AsyncPgConnection}; // *** changed to use diesel mock


// Business logic as async functions that can be shared between threads
trait Service: Send + Sync + 'static {
    /// Update value of item if new value is larger than current value.
    /// Example functino that needs multiple repo functions
    fn maximize_item(&self, id: i32, value: i32) -> impl Future<Output=Result<i32, String>> + Send;
}

// Persist the data in e.g. a database
// The repository provides a new connection and expects that repo methods are called with
trait Repository: Send + Sync + 'static {
    type Conn: Connection;

    /// Connect to data storage, or throw error if attempt failed
    fn connect(&self) -> impl Future<Output=Result<Self::Conn, String>> + Send;

    /// Get current value for item, or throw error if item doesn't exist or value is not retrievable
    fn get_item_value(&self, conn: &mut Self::Conn, id: i32) -> impl Future<Output=Result<i32, String>> + Send;

    /// Update value for item, or throw error if item doesn't exist or can't be updated
    fn update_item_value(&self, conn: &mut Self::Conn, id: i32, value: i32) -> impl Future<Output=Result<i32, String>> + Send;
}


// Connection to some data storage
#[async_trait::async_trait] // *** added
trait Connection: AsMut<Self::SpecificConn> + Send + Sync + 'static {
    type SpecificConn: Send + Sync;

    /// Provide a generic transaction as closure that is agnostic to the underlying db or ORM.
    /// Commit if closure returns Ok`, rollback on `Err`
    // THe lifetimes are wrong, and possibly more, but I don't know how to fix this method
    async fn transaction<'a, R, F>(&mut self, callback: F) -> Result<R, String> // *** changed
    where
        F: for<'r> FnOnce(&'r mut Self) -> ScopedBoxFuture<'a, 'r, Result<R, String>> + Send + 'a, // *** changed
        R: Send + 'a; // *** changed
}

struct ServiceImpl<R: Repository> {
    repo: R, // service holds a generic repository to persist date
}

// implementation for Service while keeping the repository generic
impl<R: Repository> Service for ServiceImpl<R> {
    // The service methods sometimes need to call multiple repository functions, but need
    // to ensure this is done as an atomic transaction. Instead of writing business logic to roll
    // back failed attempts on my own, I rather want to use a database transaction for this
    async fn maximize_item(&self, id: i32, value: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {

        // get new db connection wrapped into a generic object
        let mut conn = self.repo.connect().await?;

        // wrap repository tasks into an atomic but generic transaction. The repo needs
        // to ensure a transaction is atomic
        conn.transaction(|conn: &mut R::Conn| async move {

            // get value and update value are different methods, but
            // should be executed as atomic transaction here
            let current = self.repo.get_item_value(conn, id).await?;
            if value > current {
                let updated = self.repo.update_item_value(conn, id, value).await?;
                println!("Maximized item [{id}] from {current} to {updated}"); // *** added
                Ok::<i32, String>(updated)
            } else {
                println!("Kept item [{id}] at {current}, because {value} is smaller"); // *** added
                Ok::<i32, String>(current)
            }
        }.scope_boxed()).await // *** added scope_boxed
    }
}

struct RepositoryForSpecificDbType;

// implement the repository for a specific database and ORM (or a mock for testing).
// In this case it is Postgres with Diesel
impl Repository for RepositoryForSpecificDbType { // *** lifetime removed
    type Conn = ConnectionToSpecificDbType; // *** lifetime removed

    // wrap diesel connection to postgres db into a generic connection object
    async fn connect(&self) -> Result<ConnectionToSpecificDbType, String> {
        let dsn = "postgres:://root:****@localhost:my_db";
        let conn = AsyncPgConnection::establish(dsn).await.map_err(|_| "Connection failed".to_string())?;
        Ok(ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new(conn))
    }

    async fn get_item_value(&self, _conn: &mut Self::Conn, id: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
        // mocking some database lookup
        Ok(id * 2)
    }

    async fn update_item_value(&self, _conn: &mut Self::Conn, _id: i32, value: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
        // mocking some database update
        Ok(value)
    }
}

#[repr(transparent)] // *** added
struct ConnectionToSpecificDbType(AsyncPgConnection); // *** struct def changed

impl ConnectionToSpecificDbType { // *** lifetime removed
    fn new(conn: AsyncPgConnection) -> Self { // *** function changed
        Self(conn)
    }

    fn new_from_mut(conn: &mut AsyncPgConnection) -> &mut Self { // *** function changed
        #[allow(unsafe_code)]
        unsafe {
            // Transmutes a diesel connection into a ConnectionToSpecificDbType.
            // Source and result are both mutable references, lifetime of source is copied (I guess)
            // SAFETY: transparent repr is used for Self
            core::mem::transmute::<&mut AsyncPgConnection, &mut Self>(conn)
        }
    }
}

// get mutable reference to connection
impl AsMut<AsyncPgConnection> for ConnectionToSpecificDbType { // *** lifetime removed
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut AsyncPgConnection { // *** function changed
        &mut self.0
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum TransactionError<E: Send + Sync> {
    UserCaused(E),
    #[allow(dead_code)] // *** added: DieselCaused is not used currently
    DieselCaused(diesel::result::Error),
}

// A diesel transaction requires that a closure error implements `From<Error>`.
// To stay generic, handle errors in the closure and translate them into a generic error
impl<E: Send + Sync> From<diesel::result::Error> for TransactionError<E> {
    fn from(value: diesel::result::Error) -> Self {
        TransactionError::DieselCaused(value)
    }
}

#[async_trait::async_trait] // *** added
impl Connection for ConnectionToSpecificDbType { // *** lifetime removed
    type SpecificConn = AsyncPgConnection;

    // This function doesn't work
    // it should provide a generic abstraction of a transaction
    async fn transaction<'a, R, F>(&mut self, callback: F) -> Result<R, String> // *** changed
    where
        F: for<'r> FnOnce(&'r mut Self) -> ScopedBoxFuture<'a, 'r, Result<R, String>> + Send + 'a, // *** changed
        R: Send + 'a, // *** changed
    {
        // *** inner_conn def removed
        let result = self.as_mut().transaction(|diesel_conn| async move {
            println!("Entered transaction"); // *** added

            // wrap mut ref to diesel connection into connection object that implements Connection
            let inner_conn: &mut ConnectionToSpecificDbType = ConnectionToSpecificDbType::new_from_mut(diesel_conn); // *** changed

            // call closure
            let result = callback(inner_conn).await; // *** changed

            // translate into generic intermediate error type that implements From<Error>
            result.map_err(|e| TransactionError::UserCaused(e))
        }.scope_boxed()).await;

        println!("Left transaction"); // *** added

        // return result
        result.map_err(|e| format!("{e:?}").to_string())
    }
}

mod diesel_async_mock { // *** mod added
    use diesel::ConnectionResult;
    use scoped_futures::ScopedBoxFuture;

    pub struct AsyncPgConnection;

    #[async_trait::async_trait]
    pub trait AsyncConnection: Sized + Send {
        async fn establish(database_url: &str) -> ConnectionResult<Self>;

        async fn transaction<'a, R, E, F>(&mut self, callback: F) -> Result<R, E>
        where
            F: for<'r> FnOnce(&'r mut Self) -> ScopedBoxFuture<'a, 'r, Result<R, E>> + Send + 'a,
            E: From<diesel::result::Error> + Send + 'a,
            R: Send + 'a,
        {
            callback(self).await
        }
    }
    #[async_trait::async_trait]
    impl AsyncConnection for AsyncPgConnection {
        async fn establish(_database_url: &str) -> ConnectionResult<Self> {
            Ok(Self)
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // create a new service instance and define which repository implementation is used
    let service = ServiceImpl {
        repo: RepositoryForSpecificDbType
    };

    assert_eq!(service.maximize_item(5, 3).await.unwrap(), 10);
    assert_eq!(service.maximize_item(5, 8).await.unwrap(), 10);
    assert_eq!(service.maximize_item(5, 13).await.unwrap(), 13);
    assert_eq!(service.maximize_item(5, 21).await.unwrap(), 21);
}

Output:
Entered transaction
Kept item [5] at 10, because 3 is smaller
Left transaction
Entered transaction
Kept item [5] at 10, because 8 is smaller
Left transaction
Entered transaction
Maximized item [5] from 10 to 13
Left transaction
Entered transaction
Maximized item [5] from 10 to 21
Left transaction

